# How to disable Default Beep for a specific application?

Tags: windows, matlab, audio

MATLAB plays `C:\Windows\media\Windows Background.wav` at undesired moments. It's disabled via `Control Panel > Sound > Sounds > Default Beep > (None)`, and its registry key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current`. Problem is, this disables the sound for *all* applications.

A [known method](https://superuser.com/a/1804068/1010638) for per-application handling has failed. Other sounds in `Sound` are named normally, e.g. `System Notification` is `Apps\SystemNotification` - only `Default Beep`'s name uses potentially problematic syntax, `.Default`, which I suspect may be responsible.

Is there a more programmatic way to solve this? Or to disable *all* sound from `MATLAB.exe` (it doesn't show in Volume Mixer)? [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) was recommended to trace the source, but now I know what it is since I can disable it - can it provide other useful information?

Several key combinations were tried, including `DefaultBeep` and `.Default` - one example, using a different audio instead of none at all (Windows 11):

[image]

Comment: I'll change "Default Beep" to "sound" in title if needed - accepting both kinds of answers (Default Beep taking priority).

Comment: Why does MATLAB make Windows sounds at all? It has never done that for me. When do the sounds occur? On errors?

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, an incomplete solution is [`beep off`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/beep.html), but doesn't fix e.g. pressing arrow-down when focused on empty console window. It's a [decade-old problem](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36303-can-the-beep-be-turned-off-within-matlab).

Comment: @Adriaan it does beep a lot for me too, e.g. on the command line autocomplete, etc.